# Projection onto an ideal in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

This might be a basic question but I'm not seen it through. Let $\mathcal A$ be a C$^*$-algebra and $I$ a two sided closed ideal, we define the projection $\pi:\mathcal A \to I$ given by $$\pi(a)=1_I\cdot a$$
where $1_I$ is the unit of $I$. This should be a well defined continuous projection.

If we consider the case where we have no unit in $I$ could we take an approximate unit of $I$ and just define the projection with it? I mean something like $\tilde{\pi}:\mathcal A\to I $ such that
$$\tilde{\pi}(a)=\lim_\lambda e_\lambda a$$
where $\{e_\lambda\}_{\lambda}$ is an approximation unit in $I$, I'm not even sure this limit exists. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Within $C([0,1])$, consider the ideal of functions that vanish at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If an ideal as the unital element, then it is the whole algebra, for $ab$ is in $I$, for all $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $I$, so that also $a=a1$ in $I$ for all $a$, since $1$ is in $I$.